# Practicing Reverse Engineering To Find Default Password From Router Firmware

Tags: firmware

I am currently practicing reverse engineering to look for the default password of the Linksys V1.5 firmware here https://www.linksys.com/us/support-article?articleNum=148613

I tried to use binwalk to get more information from the file but do not know where to go from here.  Almost no useful information from what I have seen from hexdump and strings command.  Is there any other recommended tools to use or strategies?

Comment: Did you use binwalk to extract or just view information? If there are known file formats, it should give you enough information to extract things manually, but it will also do it for you automatically.

Comment: Tried binwalk -e to extract the files but couldn't figure out anything useful.

Comment: After extracting the bin with `binwalk -e` take a look at `2D20`, that looks to be where the interesting stuff is at

Comment: and you tried `admin:admin` ?

Comment: @streetster Did you use a hex editor to look at that file? Still trying to learn and don't know how to go from here.  I do know it was admin but was wondering where to look to find that information in the firmware.

Comment: I did find something that suggested login details were admin/admin but I wasn't able to extract any binaries or anything concrete (hence comment rather than answer). Yup, I used `xxd`.